# How to sort in mongo based on a field but give preference to documents satisfying certain condition?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a mongodb collection on which I was sorting based on their last updation date using `{ $sort : { updated_at : -1 } }`.
Now I am trying to update my query to still sort by `updated_at` but give first preference to those documents which satisfy a certain condition like a field's array length in greater than zero i.e. `{'img.0': { $exists: true }}`

But how do I combine it in the sort query?

My requirement is that the query should first return all the documents in which `img` length is greater than 0 sorted by `updated_at` and then list the remaining documents sorted by `updated_at`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** where your pipeline creates an extra field that holds a flag representing the criteria above and you can use it as your sort option together with the `updated_at` field:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "img": 1,
            "updated_at": 1,
            "other_fields": 1,
            "hasImages": {
                "$cond": [
                    { 
                        "$ne": [ 
                            {
                                "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$img", [] ] }
                            }, 
                            0 
                        ]
                    },
                    1, 0
                ]               
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "hasImages": -1, "updated_at": - 1
        }
    }
])
```

---

Check the test demo below

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm! :-)

Comment: @SurenderThakran No worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("collectionName").find({'img.0': { $exists: true }}).sort({ updated_at : -1 })
```

or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {'img.0': { $exists: true }}},
    {$sort: {"updated_at" : -1}}
  ])
```

Comment: this will only return those documents which satisfy the condition and sort them by updated_at. I want to FIRST return all such documents but after that get the REMAINING documents sorted by updated_at

Comment: you mean, you want to sort all those documents which satisfy the criteria, and then append all those documents as well which dont satisfy query. correct?

Comment: Yes. I only want to give first preference to documents which satisfy the criteria but show the remaining documents as well.